# Upgrading Entity Framework 4.0 to 6.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, edmx

Need to upgrade Entity Framework and edmx from 4.0 to 6.0 version. Later version of Visual Studio which were used was VS 2012 but now I want to update the entity and `.edmx` in Visual Studio 2013. Tried to install latest version of Entity Framework from NuGet packages, still it seems like it's not working properly.

How to upgrade Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: You are most likely using the old ObjectContext, I would suggest upgrading to the new DbContext by recreating the entitymodel. Also what is not working properly? There is not enough information to help you further.

Comment: when i build my project i'm getting this error ''The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
"

Comment: It seems you didn't get the nuget packed installed properly, see if you have the latest nuget package manager (Tools - Extensions And Updates) installed and try installing EntityFramework again.